# USA Heat Map with D3 doesn't size properly in IE

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, d3.js, svg, cross-browser

I'm creating a heat map of the US for my application (which uses Bootstrap), and in Chrome and FireFox the map correctly sizes to the width of the panel it resides in and adjusts the height proportionately.  In Internet Explorer, however, it is only 150px high.

Resizing the window in Chrome and FireFox causes the image to grow/shrink.  In IE, the image will shrink if you make the window small enough, but never increases in size over the initial 150px high.

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Map</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="Map"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The map is drawn with this code (the json variable is set elsewhere):

```
function DrawMap(data) {
    projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
        .scale(1000)
        .translate([0, 0]);

    path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

    svg = d3.select("#Map")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("class", "map")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height);

    svg
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "background")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .on("click", click);

    g = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(495, 230)")
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "states");

    states = g.selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("name", function(d) { return "path-" + d.properties.abbr; })
        .style("fill", "#fff")
        .on("click", click);
    labels = g.selectAll("text")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; })
        .attr("name", function (d) { return 'label-' + d.properties.abbr; })
        .attr("dx", function (d) { return d.properties.dx || "0"; })
        .attr("dy", function (d) { return d.properties.dy || "0.35em"; })
        .on("click", click)
        .text(function (d) { return d.properties.abbr; });
}
```

I've created a fiddle that shows the behavior (I removed AK and HI for simplicity, and removed VA because for some reason it was causing a rendering issue in the fiddle which didn't occur in my app - didn't change the behavior, though):

http://jsfiddle.net/Nf3Jy/ (to see what I'm trying to fix you need to use IE)

In our app we use knockout and get the heat map data, but to keep this simple I removed that (just explaining in case you wonder why some of the code is more complicated than it has to be for the example).

Please help me figure out how to get it to size properly in IE.  I tried running the following after drawing the chart and on window resize:

```
$('#Map').height($('#Map').width() * height / width);
```

That does cause it to size/resize across browsers, but I don't like it for two reasons - it's not necessary in Chrome and FireFox, and it doesn't work when you maximize and restore.  On maximize it does redraw properly, but on restore I'm guessing the resize event fires before the window changes (?) so you see a white box where the map should be until you resize again, at which time it redraws properly.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use something like this:

```
div#us-chart
{
transform:scale(.35,.35);
-ms-transform:scale(2,4); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:scale(.35,.35); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this to my fiddle, but it just makes it looks really odd.

`#Map
{
    transform:scale(.35,.35);
    -ms-transform:scale(2,4); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:scale(.35,.35); /* Safari and Chrome */
}`